# xpath search within search result

Tags: ruby, xpath

in ruby I have selected rows with:

```
doc.css('table tr').each do |row|
  puts row.xpath('a')[0].text
end
```

So fetching the rows works, but when I want to get the link from each row, it wont find it. When I try `//a` it will get the first link on the page, not the one in the selected row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use relative path inside inner elements, so using something like this should do the trick:

```
...
    row.xpath('.//a')
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, very easy, `.//a` did it for this case.